# "Invalid region specified" error with docker-machine create command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, docker-machine

I'm creating EC2 instance from terminal and I'm using `--amazonec2-region eu-west-2` flag to indicate London.

I'm recalling it used to work in the past, why I'm getting `Error setting machine configuration from flags provided: Invalid region specified` now ?

Comment: `--amazonec2-region` ? which command are you using?

Comment: `docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-access-key abc --amazonec2-secret-key xyz --amazonec2-region eu-west-2 instance_name`